# Q: How does wifi AP providers (e.g Starbucks,McD) pushes out "Sign In to surf website" notifications to customers, and how to implement that in JAVA?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, push-notification

I have 2 parts to my question. First is just a general question and second is more into app development and coding.

How does Starbucks/Coffee Bean/McDonalds pushes out notification whenever we as customers connect to their WIFI AP? They will push out notifications like "Sign In to proceed using the internet" in the status bar, and then redirects us to their website before we can start using the internet.

I am trying to create an app that does just that by creating a personal hotspot(that will have internet access), and whenever customers are logged into my hotspot, they will receive that same notification. My intention is to just direct them to a 'sign in' page in their browser, and once they click sign in, they will again be directed to my personal website. After that, they are free to surf any websites they want to.

So is it possible to do just that? I only want the app to be installed in my phone, and not in my customers phone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm deducing a lot of this, but I don't see how else it could work.

The wifi hotspots you are referring to are themselves little web servers, in addition to being participants in the world wide web.  When a browser sends a URL out, it eventually gets to a web server (we won't go into the DNS system here), and the web server -- a machine listening on one or two ports, ready to accept a URL via socket and return something in response -- responds to it.

In the case you're talking about, the little wifi web server stores the URL sent and, regardless of what it is, sends back the "login to continue" page, and ensures that it is responded to.  Once it is, then it does its normal thing with the original URL, which in this case means it sends it out to the internet cloud for interpretation like a normal wifi hotspot would.

As future URLs are sent, the wifi hotspot ensures that the login has occurred -- perhaps it just uses the URL of the machine as a key to information about when it logged in last, or a cookie, there are a couple of ways -- and if there is a current login session, then it again passes the URL out to the internet cloud.

In order to do this in Java on your phone, you would need control of the socket input/output of the hotspot; you would have to be able to read the input, determine whether the login had occurred, and only then either pass along the incoming URL or store it so the login could take place.  I don't know how you would do that.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a "captive portal" - all new users connecting through the hotspot will have their HTTP requests redirected to this portal. Once you register, your IP-address is known and the redirect no longer occurs.

How this works on mobile devices is typically that when you connect to a hotspot your phone will try to access a well known address and when the redirection occurs to a HTTP-AUTH response it will then open the captive portal as part of the setup process. For instance in the case of the iPhone apple will try to access 'phobos.apple.com' which is why you'll often see this in the pop-up when you are trying to access a "other" website on an non-authenticated access point.

As regards doing this in Java, I think you will have a few problems on your hands. Typically Java only provides network access at TCP/UDP layers and above. Now what you *could* do is have your application acting as a "proxy" such that it relays all network activity through it, but this would be a heavy load for your application. It also would not have the transparency of the type of solutions you would be used to. Your users may also have to be told to access your site directly.

Your typical captive portal has a few different actors involved and a number of different protocols beneath the application layer. The Access Point needs to "know" whether a user is authorised or not (and thus is redirected to the portal, or gets to access the wider internet); The portal needs to be able to notify the portal upon authentication; 802.1x is used for the initial handshaking; DHCP to assign the IP-address based on MAC address.

Comment: Thanks for telling me the term captive portal. Okay, assuming that the users doesn't have to sign in, and go straight to my website, can it be done? 

So far in my app, I managed to enable hotspot, and to view the MAC address of customer's android phone. What can I do thereafter? Is there a way of coding a URL inside my hotspot app, and then send that over to the client's phone?

Comment: Unless they are already "waiting for" or "looking for" this notification there might not be a way to do this directly without prior registration. What I would investigate would be the configurability of the hotspot. It should have rudimentary routing capability. You want to set it up so that it redirects clients to your URL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353911/using-android-phone-as-wifi-web-server